# How can I delay ALL scripts for a specified duration?

Tags: javascript, delay, wait

I'm working on a strictly javascript based game.  What I want is for certain bits of information be printed out to the screen in regular intervals.  Easy enough?  Yes... but the problem is that I only want to delay how some text is printed out to the screen (adding text to the innherHTML of a div).

I'm aware of setInterval and setTimeout methods, but the problem with those is that it only delays how long it takes for a certain function to be called while the rest of the script continues to run.  What I want is for everything to pause, to not allow javascript to advance at all until a certain duration has passed.

I can think of a workaround--instead of writing straight to the innerHTML property, write to a queue of strings, then use a setInterval method to display a line of text if there is anything waiting in the queue.  Not hard to do, but I'm wondering if Javascript has any kind of pause-all command that will do the same thing.  For now I'm avoiding jQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing like that in JS. Using a queue seems to be a good choice.

Comment: If the code is written in a modular way why would you need to pause the whole script when you can pause just the method that inserts the messages in the div? 

Perhaps you should reconsider some architectural choices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there is no such thing. Javascript is asynchronous and you can't stop other "threads". What you can do is to have some global variable or main program class method that stops the game processes.
Simple pauseable game class:

```
function Game() {
    var run = true;
    this.pause = function() {
        run = false;
    }
    this.go = function() {
        if(run)
          return false;
        run = true;
        heartbeat();
    }
    function heartbeat() {
       /*Do game rendering or whatever you want to pause*/

       if(run)
         setTimeout(heartbeat, 100);  //tick
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! In this scenario I don't have use for a pause button.  My game is a sort of a match-the-sequence thing in which the player only has a short time to memorize a short sequence of symbols before parroting them back.  I could have a black div cover up everything on the screen , but I don't think that is needed.

Comment: May I see your game? I'm a bit curious.

Answer (score 0):

You can "freeze" the page itself with something like:

```
var start = new Date().getTime(), delay = 5000; // milliseconds
while(new Date().getTime() < start+delay) {}
```

However this will freeze the entire browser too and usually results in a crashed browser, a "Not Responding" box from Windows, or a "this script is taking a long time to run, kill it?" question.

The "proper" way to do it would be to have a "isPaused" boolean that you can flip on or off, and if it's off then functions try to run themselves again. Something like this:

```
function pauseCheck(thisobj,argobj) {
    if( isPaused) {
        setTimeout(function() {argobj.callee.apply(thisobj,Array.prototype.slice(argobj,0));},250);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then in your other functions:

```
function doSomething(x,y) {
    if( pauseCheck(this,arguments)) {
        // function body here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, when one wants to avoid OOP. Good work with callee :)